# Terminology shift with maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven, deployment, release, terminology, maven-release-plugin

Usually developers say that we make **build**, than **deploy** to servers in different environments (integration, test, production). Deployment to production environment is **release**.

Now with Maven and [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) it becomes unclear how to express yourself explicitly.
Because what maven-release-plugin does, is building and `deploy`ing to Nexus server.

Then we started saying "to release" with meaning "to use maven-release-plugin to make build and put it on Nexus"

**What words do you use when deploying to servers in different environments and releasing to production?**

Comment: Technically, cutting a release is exactly what the release-plugin does (generating artifacts and performing SCM operations - tag, commits...). Ops people might call "release" the operation to deploy a release in production, but for me it is rather a "production roll-out".

Comment: OK, use words "product roll-out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my world, a release is a deployment to production. What the maven release plugin [does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3661037/33434) is quite non-standard. I'd just call that a *maven-release*